# insert into a table across all tables in a single library SAS

Tags: sql-server, sas, sas-macro

I want to do the same insertion in the DSN table with all the existing tables in the LIB1 library at the same time

this code example is applied for a single table TAB , I want to apply it for all the tables in LIB1, how can I do that? THANKS

````
LIBNAME lib1 'U:\Dossier';
run; 

proc sql noprint;
select nliteral(name) into :varlist separated by ','
   from dictionary.columns
   where libname="KOL" and memname='DSN' and name^='ID_F'
;
insert into KOL.DSN (&varlist. ) select &varlist.
from lib1.TAB 
;
quit;  ```
````

Comment: I want to insert into the DSN table, all the tables exist in the LIB1 library, how can I do that, thank you,: like this:
insert into KOL.DSN (&varlist. ) select &varlist.
from lib1.*

Comment: Okey , I have clearly specified the request, thank you TOm

Comment: Add a proper title. Add all the relevant information in the question itself, not the comments. You won't get any answers if people see an unclear question. They'll simply skip it

Comment: okey, I corrected the title and clarified the question

Comment: What should happen if some of the tables in the library have different structure than KOL.DSN? (i.e. If KOL.DSN2 does not have some (or none) of the columns of DSN)

Comment: generally have same structure and if other tables do not have same structure I have to deal with it manually!!!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the generated SQL INSERT statement is the same as this normal SAS procedure call.

```
proc append base=KOL.DSN data=KOL.DSN(drop=ID_F); 
run;
```

That seems like a silly thing to do, but you could easily generate it from a list of the dataset names.

Let's assume that you actually want to copy the data from a different library than the one where you are writing it.  Say the librefs are IN and OUT.

First get the list of members.  Perhaps just the list of members that have that ID_F variable.

```
proc contents data=IN._ALL_ noprint out=contents(where=(upcase(name)='ID_F')); run;
```

Then use that list to generate the code;

```
data _null_;
  set contents;
  call execute(catx(' '
     ,'proc append'
     ,'base=',catx('.','out',memname)
     ,'data=',catx('.',libname,memname),'(drop=ID_F);'
     ,'run;'
  ));
run;
```